# Assertion failure in +[Sync changes:inEntityNamed:predicate:parent:inContext:dataStack:completion:]

Tags: ios, json, hypersync

I'm using [Sync from HyperOslo](https://github.com/hyperoslo/Sync) i get a simple JSON object:

Printed json object (user) =>

```
[{
    email = "email@email.fr";
    name = "Damian Menestrel";
}]
```

...to convert in Core Data User with the method:

```
Sync.changes(user , inEntityNamed: "User", dataStack: DataManager.dataStack, completion: { (response ) -> Void in

})
```

The app crash with this error:

> Assertion failure in +[Sync
>   changes:inEntityNamed:predicate:parent:inContext:dataStack:completion:],
>   .../Pods/Sync/Source/Sync.m:77

Where this error come from?

---

My CodeData model is :

[image]

User.swift

```
import Foundation
import CoreData
import UIKit

class User: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var email: String?
    @NSManaged var name: String?
}
```

Comment: See: https://github.com/hyperoslo/Sync#crash-on-nsparameterassert

Comment: This is not a Core Data issue, it is an issue with the third party framework.  Tags updated to reflect that fact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer:**
Just add a `remoteID` attribute to your Core Data model as a primary key and it will work. This will map to the `id` attribute in your JSON.

**Long answer:**

Taken from the [Primary Key](https://github.com/hyperoslo/Sync/blob/master/README.md#primary-key) section on Sync's README.

> Sync requires your entities to have a primary key, this is important
>   for diffing otherwise Sync doesn’t know how to differentiate between
>   entries.
>
> By default **Sync** uses `id` from the JSON and `remoteID` from Core
>   Data as the primary key. You can mark any attribute as primary key by
>   adding `hyper.isPrimaryKey` and the value `YES`.
>
> For example in our [Designer
>   News](https://github.com/hyperoslo/Sync/tree/master/DesignerNews)
>   project we have a `Comment` entity that uses `body` as the primary
>   key.

[image: Custom primary key]

Comment: Thanks Elvis. Btw, nice job ;)